# Prove there's $M>0$ such that: $f(x)\le Mx^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, three-times differentiable function and $f(0)=0$, $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$. Prove there's $M>0$ such that $f(x)\le Mx^2$. Hint: use Taylor formula.

So following the hint and the fact that $f$ differentiable three times:
$$f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2 + R_2(x)$$

$f(0) = 0$. Simplifying:
$$f(x) = f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2 + R_2(x)$$

We also know that $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$. Therefore:

$$f(x) = f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2 + R_2(x) \ge 0$$

What should I do next?

Comment: If $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$, wouldn't that mean that $f$ attains a minimum value at $x = 0$?

Comment: Are you implying that $f'(0)=0$?

Comment: Having a minimum value at a point does not imply that the derivative at that point is zero, (minimum values attained at endpoints) but it does in this case. The function is either the zero function, in which $f'(0) = 0$, or it has a turning point at $x = 0$. We know this because $f$ is differentiable, and thus continuous (so there can't be any sharp turns). So yes, I'm implying that.

Comment: "Turning point" = "Extremum point"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $[-1,1]$ is closed and bounded (compact), and $f',f''$ is bounded on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Elimination continuous function on compact domain has a compact range---basic topology.

Comment: All you know about $f'$ is that it has the MVT property (Darboux's theorem). You can't tell $f'$ is continuous. Aren't you?

Comment: @Elimination you said its 3-time differentiable...

Comment: @Elimination Besides, you should use Lagrange remainder...

Comment: So we have:  $f(x)= f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2 + \frac{f^{(3)}(0)}{3!}x^3 \le 0 + Ax + Bx^2 + Cx^3$. where $A,B,C$ are the max values at the interval.

Comment: @Elimination $f(x)=\underbrace{f(0)}_{=0}+\underbrace{f'(0)}_{=0}x+\frac{f''(x^*)}{2}x^2,x^* \in[0,x)$

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much @Troy Woo